# Is timing nslookup running in subprocess.run effective?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, timing, nslookup

This is part of a script meant to time some public DNS server's name resolution and return the quickest. It usually returns the same top five with values between 100ms and 300ms

Will the times measured in this way be accurate for what you can expect using the servers on the same system running the script?

```
for ns in nsinfo:

    start = time.time()
    subprocess.run(f"nslookup google.com {nsinfo[ns]['ip']}", shell=False, stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL)
    end = time.time()

    nsinfo[ns]['res'] = end - start
```

Comment: Perhaps use the [socket](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html) module instead? I don't see a need to use `nslookup`.

Comment: @SeanBreckenridge I will try that. I haven't learned socket yet, seems like the next logical thing to learn.